# How to restrict directory search to perticular directory in google desktop search?

Tags: search, desktop

I have installed goolag and google desktop. Google desktop search searches all drives and gives search result. Now i want to restrict search to particular directory. How do i do that?

(goolag code consist of index.php, mail.php, image.php, fonctions.php, fichier.php, goolag.css )
Link: http://www.asabox.com/goolag/index_en.htm 2/25/10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think that the only solution is exclude all directories except those required.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but I want to integrate google desktop search with my application which is in drupal (framework of php). Thus need to put it on Linux server. Thus it need to be done though code. Can't use exclude directory (through control panel)